# <pe:keyFilter > not working in <ui:repeat>. Throwing Exception for id not found

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

`<pe:keyFilter>` is working with single `<p:inputText>` but when i go for inputText in repeat it is not working and throwing an exception.

Like

```
   <p:inputText value="text2" id="text2" />
   <pe:keyFilter for="text2"  regEx="/[ABC]/i"/>
```

It is working fine but below code is not working and throwing exception for id text-0 not found

```
   <ui:repeat var="answer" value="#{answerBean.answerList}" varStatus="answerStatus" >
      <p:inputText value="#{answer.answerText}" id="text-#{answerStatus.index}" />
      <pe:keyFilter for="text-#{answerStatus.index}" regEx="/[ABC]/i" />
   </ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about forcing unique IDs inside JSF iteration components. JSF already does that all by itself. Simply get rid of `varStatus` and all unnecessity related to that and let JSF do its job.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{answerBean.answerList}" var="answer">
   <p:inputText id="text" ... />
   <pe:keyFilter for="text" ... />
</ui:repeat>
```

It's only necessary if you were using `<c:forEach>` taghandler instead of `<ui:repeat>` component. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)